# Angularjs directive ng-hide in cell template is not binding on change in grid data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular directive ng-hide in cell template is not binding with latest data on change in grid data. Please check plunkr for more details :- http://plnkr.co/edit/rj0PrfyzeyVeV8Q8RWtG?p=preview
In plunker template field is not updating with change in data.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.gridOpts = {        
        columnDefs: [
          { name:'name', field: 'name' },
          { name:'isActive', field: 'isActive'},
          { name:'template',cellTemplate:'<div><a ng-hide={{row.entity.isActive=="Y"}}>Active</a><a ng-hide={{row.entity.isActive=="N"}}>Deactive</a></div>'}
        ]
  };

  $scope.waiting = "Waiting...";
  $timeout(function () {
    $scope.gridOpts.data = [{ name: 'Bob' ,isActive:'Y'}];
  }, 3000)
  .then(function() {
    $timeout( function() {
      $scope.gridOpts.data = [{ name: 'John',isActive:'N' }];
    }, 3000);
    $scope.waiting = "Waiting again...";
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a expression inside the [`ng-hide`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide)

> The ngHide directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngHide attribute.

so your `ng-hide` **should be like**

```
..ng-hide=row.entity.isActive=="Y"..
```

**not like** this interpolation,

```
.. ng-hide={{row.entity.isActive=="Y"}}..
```

here is the updated [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/8prxVDdB0ebXQLme7hTr?p=preview)